# Multisite warning Undefined variable

Tags: multisite

After the update 5.6.1, for a user role with non-admin permission, I noticed a warning concerning Multisite that indicate an Undefined variable :

```
Notice: Undefined variable: type in multisite_civicrm_selectWhereClause() (line 229 of /var/data/sites/reveal/public_html/sites/default/files/civicrm/ext/org.civicrm.multisite/multisite.php).
```

This might be linked : any request for let's say the list of contact in a group gives a 500 *Internal Server Error*. The *Recent log messages* always indicate the Undefined variable Notice.

As a non admin and to fully benefit of the Multisite setting, the permission for this role doesn't include **view and edit all contacts**.
How can I dig in this ?

Comment: Hi, thanks for adding the resolution.  It is clearer to everyone that the issue is resolved if you put your update as an answer rather than with the question.  You can then accept the answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

==> I found the trouble : that was in the role setting : Multisite: view/edit/list all contacts in domain was not selected for this role… I my case, all the site share same user and roles along the sites. But the actual setting needs to be defined in each site. Therefore the warning was indeed accurate and indicating a wrong setting for the role.